# convert mfc dialog based windows application to web based

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I have a MFC dialog based windows application developed using C++ (both frontend and backend).
I need to convert my MFC dialog to a web-based application, without changing the backend, which is developed in C++.

Can i get a suggestion on the technology that can be used? (i.e. asp.net or wpf or ....)

Comment: If the current application is non-trivial, this is not going to be a simple port.  There will be a lot of work involved - similar in size to a complete rewrite of the front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at CPPCMS (http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main). I have used it to add a web-interface to an existing application and it worked very well.

You will have to create a new front-end with CPPCMS and then link it to your existing backend. This is however all still possible within one process/application.

CPPCMS can run its embedded http server or it can interface with something like apache through fcgi.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: Does the client machine need any installation to run the cppcms web application ?

Comment: @Jahnavi no, the client would be any web browser (chrome, safari, IE, etc.) with no additional plugins required. The server you create with CPPCMS would serve the required HTML, JavaScript, Style, etc. files.

Comment: thanks for the information

Comment: @Jahnavi if you are interested in building mobile apps with web technologies you can have a look at http://ionicframework.com/, but this isn't really related to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

MFC dialog won't work with web based. You can try following:

1. Convert the code of present MFC app to a C++ dll which will export all the useful functions you are using.
2. Create an ASP.net web application which will have a form similar to your dialog.
3. Call your dll from ASP.net. Refer following
   http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/208615/How-to-invoke-Cplusplus-DLL-in-ASP-NET.
4. You will have to write the code to call the dll and display results in form.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion